# Changing iOS app icon in future version

Tags: ios, icons, version

Is it possible to change the app icon in the future release in iOS.I dint find any document in  developer library which states this.Does apple allow to change the app icon in the future update.

Are there any app in the store which have changed the app icon in there update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you update your apps in the apps store, you need to resubmit the application again. In this way you can include your updated icons. In addition, you can update your logo,screenshots and description on the itunes connect when you submit your updated apps.

Comment: @kaar3k If you are happy with the answer, you should accept the solution. Click on the "white" tick (check mark) beside this answer. Cheers. Vito

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I recently changed my entire icon set in an update (to a completely different image), and it got through the App Store review process just fine.

Comment: Thanks @matt for solving my dilema.